# How do we deal with "the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade" in bazel

Tags: bazel

When we use maven, this job can be easily solved by the maven-shaded-plugin. But for bazel, how do we deal with this?

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what do you want to achieve? Ideally, tell us what the problem is, not how other build system solves it.

Comment: As I said in the problem body. I am asking how bazel deal with package conflicts. When you use some jar as your project dependency, your project and your dependency may depends on same jar but with different version. I am asking how bazel solve this. In maven, it can be done via maven shade plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Bazel doesn't deal with multiple jar versions right now and probably won't in the future as it is considered bad practice. Bazel considers the first version of the jar found on the classpath. A workaround would be using [jarjar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jarjar/) to repackage one (or more) of the library versions and use that as a dependency.

Comment: Any profound arguments for saying "multiple jar" is bad practice? If I two dependencies depend on Guava 17 and Guava 22 as we all know these two Guava are not compatible, how will you deal with this?

Comment: @zhexuany - in pre-Java9 runtime you have flat classpath unless you have some custom module system like OSGi and JEE/EAP. Flat classpath can have libraries in different version but JVM will load first anyway - it will be a problem when some class request class available only in second library version and it won't work with classes previously loaded from first version of library. Bazel doesn't do anything special here - just JVM wasn't designed for it before Java9. How do you want to use two not compatible Guava versions in single application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this https://github.com/johnynek/bazel_jar_jar repository useful. It provides a easy to use rules to manipulate jarjar.